# How to validate only one binding property

Tags: c#, validation, razor, model

i've a RazorPage with a modal partial page inside. In the RazorPage i show my main class object(like Customer details) and the partial page i will insert a new property(example a new address of my Customer) of my main class object. Data validation works well(I use DataAnnotations) but my ModelState is invalid. This because PageModel validate the all page and in this case my main class have an object(Address) empty that cause the not valid state.
There is a way to validate only one specific BindProperty?

**UPDATE:**

I've find this method:
ModelState.Clear();
TryValidateModel(model);

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   ...
}
It works, but i don't know if is the correct way to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find this method: ModelState.Clear(); TryValidateModel(model)